# Is there a wysiwyg editor for angular dart yet?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am looking for a WYSIWYG editor that I can hook into my angular dart applications, but I had no luck yet.
I tried to create a binding myself for tinyMCE, but it was only one way and of course for a nice UI you need both.. :-/

Is someone aware of a project to have a decent wysiwyg editor for angular dart?
I mean for many applications this is really vital for non technical users to have such a thing to format their input...

Answer (score 2):

There don't appear to be any AngularDart editors (yet), but there are editors for Angular, such as:

http://ngmodules.org/modules/angular-wysiwyg
[image: Angular WYSIWYG Editor]

You should be able to use this; though you'd need to use [JS proxies](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/js-dart-interop/) to interact with it a little.

That said, I personally think WYSWYG editors are overrated, and something like Markdown would be better; much easier to work with, and limits the damage the users can do ;-)

Comment: Personally I'd agree, but customers often demand WYSIWYG editors as they don't want to bother with markdown or something like that